# What is the average weight and price of a telecom satellite?

Tags: communication-satellite

I found a source estimating the average weight of commercial communications satellites and then I think maybe there is more such data about price and launch price too.

And then my question is about the average weight, price and launch price for such satellites. Doesn't have to be an absolute average. An average range is good enough too.

A typical weather satellite carries a price tag of \$290 million; a spy satellite might cost an additional \$100 million.

See for example in Defense Security & Monitor's *Average Commercial Communications Satellite Launch Mass Declines, Again:*

> [The average size, or launch mass, of commercial communications satellites is declining. After the average launch mass reached a peak of 4,424 kilograms in 2012, it declined to 3,578 kilograms in 2013 and 2,755 kilograms in 2014.](https://dsm.forecastinternational.com/wordpress/2015/07/13/average-commercial-communications-satellite-launch-mass-declines-again/#:%7E:text=The%20average%20size%2C%20or%20launch,and%202%2C755%20kilograms%20in%202014.)

Comment: You had the identical link showing twice so I deleted once instance and made it easier to see. Feel free to edit further if this is not the way you wanted it to display, but just pasting the raw link with its `#:~:text=` seemed unwieldly.

Comment: I expect this number to be well below 1,000 kg, maybe even 500 kg this year. I don't think you can get any meaningful information from this average. Satellites are just way too different from each other.

Comment: Well that means the mass reduced at least three times comparing with 8 years ago. That's an impressive change

Comment: No, it's not impressive - it's just because of a different approach.SpaceX launched hundreds of tiny satellites into low orbit instead of a few large ones to GEO.